# android below getId not working programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-relativelayout

i have some xml layout file.this is a my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_categorry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i wrote some code witch can add  layout programmatically.this is a my code

```
staticlayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
            staticlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

            ImageView add_btn = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            add_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            //
            //
            add_btn.setLayoutParams(parms2);
            add_btn.setOnClickListener(new listener());

            staticlayout.addView(add_btn);

            parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rot);
            staticlayout.setLayoutParams(parms);
            mainlayout.addView(static layout);
```

it's working perfect.now i want to add another layout,witch would be below layout with i add programmatically.
this is a my full code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout myImage, mainlayout;
private ImageView img;
RelativeLayout staticlayout;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myImage = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rot);
    mainlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_categorry);

    parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            staticlayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
            staticlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

            ImageView add_btn = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            add_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            //
            //
            add_btn.setLayoutParams(parms2);
            add_btn.setOnClickListener(new listener());

            staticlayout.addView(add_btn);

            parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rot);
            staticlayout.setLayoutParams(parms);
            mainlayout.addView(staticlayout);
            // parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rot);

        }
    });

}

class listener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams costomparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        relativelayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AB3232"));

        ImageView add_btn = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        add_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imagelayoutparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imagelayoutparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        imagelayoutparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        //
        //
        add_btn.setLayoutParams(imagelayoutparam);
        relativelayout.addView(add_btn);

        costomparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, staticlayout.getId());
        relativelayout.setLayoutParams(costomparam);
        mainlayout.addView(relativelayout);

    }
}
```

}

at the moment this part does not working

```
costomparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, staticlayout.getId());
```

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: plz add your logcat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you doing:

`staticlayout.addView(add_btn);`

please try to add something like

`staticlayout.setId(999);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call `setId` to your `staticlayout`before calling `staticlayout.getId()`.

Create a resource named ids.xml in values folder.
Yours should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="your_static_layout_id" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Comment: @chromelend no need to confuse about the integer, just write something random like 1. The point is, your staticlayoutbefore need an id, it doesnt matter the id's value :)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, but where did you add your staticLayout? make sure you have added staticlayout before calling staticlayout.getId() and you have also set an id to your staticLayout (which is missing in your code snippets), otherwise your desired rule should not work expectedly